# Cocoapods use_frameworks with Objective C and Swift mixed project causes issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have just started working on Swift 4.0 with my current Objective C project. Everything went fine until I wished to use `pods` for `ALCameraViewController` which is built in swift and my previous `pods` are in Objective C, so I can't enable "use_frameworks!".

Even if I enable it my project builds successfully but app crashes right away at launch with error message saying

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Amplitude_iOS.framework/Amplitude_iOS
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/44F47AE7-3928-450C-A8F4-5C708C996E43/RydeDev.app/RydeDev
  Reason: image not found
```

This `Amplitude_iOS` is one of my Objective C `pods`.

I referred to so many posts on SO and GitHub but nothing is works out for me.

I thought of a way to use Swift libraries by manual installation and  without `pods` but I think it'll not a good approach considering I might use some other libraries as well for Swift.

My `pods`

```
use_frameworks!

target '<My App>' do
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'JSONModel', '~> 1.2'
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Analytics', '~> 3.0'
pod 'LGSideMenuController', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 3.11.1'
pod 'JDFTooltips'
pod 'Branch'
pod 'Stripe’
pod 'YYModel'
pod 'ALCameraViewController'

end
```

So please help me fix this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show Pod file So We can see what all pods you had installed and try creating a sample to check

Comment: Updated the question with current pods.